# Office 365 REST API list resources (meeting rooms)

Tags: api, office365, outlook-restapi

I have a question about Office365 REST API. Is there a way to obtain list of resources - meeting room calendars.

I can only get meetings that will take place in room if I know meeting room username.

https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/users/room1@xxxx.onmicrosoft.com/calendars

Can I list all meeting rooms and obtain their calendars?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [Azure AD Graph API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh974476.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to query the list of users. However, there is no field in the API that marks a user as being a conference room. Depending on how your organization creates and names rooms, maybe you can find a filter that will only return rooms.

After that, it's just a matter of [implementing the client credential flow](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2015/01/21/building-demon-or-service-apps-with-office-365-mail-calendar-and-contacts-apis-oauth2-client-credential-flow.aspx) so you can access multiple mailboxes.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I love your blog post and Django sample app.It really helps understand the whole process.
One more question. Do you maybe know any python examples for implementation of Client Credentials Grant Flow using X509 keys?

Comment: I think I found your repo that does just that: https://github.com/jasonjoh/python_clientcred :)

Comment: Yep, that will hopefully help :).

Comment: @JasonJohnston Any plans to add such a flag to distinguish between "real" users and resources? Basing on lack of first or surname is a bit tricky...

Comment: @GaSacchi Simply get events for this "user", using resource email address.

Comment: @GaSacchi I'm using Graph API

Comment: @KrzysztofWolny Graph API should have the same limitations as Outlook API. Are you using a service app?

Comment: @GaSacchi yes, service app.

Comment: The Hyperlink in the answer is not working anymore, google search did not bring up any new locations. Any chance someone still has a copy of the text? Looking for exactly this!