# O365 API endpoint to get room directory

Tags: office365

I have been using the O365 Calendar API to get calendar events of rooms in an organisation. At the minute I am using a hardcoded list of room emails.

On the O365 web app, I am able to view a room directory of all of the rooms in the organisation and I am wondering if there is an endpoint in the O365 where I can get all of the rooms in this directory programatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meeting Rooms are stored as User objects in Azure AD. You should be able to query them through the [Azure AD Graph API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn151678.aspx).

Comment: Unfortunately, according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29628035/office-365-rest-api-list-resources-meeting-rooms there is no way to determine which user is a room. You can guess by having no given and surname set, but it's a hack... There is no way to get other properties for resource like type, location, capacity...